# Attempting to require a module from a global script in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I `require` in a global script from a module I wrote that has an `import` in it? On its own, this leads to the `import` being interpreted as part of the script, and an error saying that I cannot use it outside of modules, but I would like to just have a script that makes use of modules using `require`. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Anyone know what it might be?